# Postgres в докере создается без пользователей

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Создаю сервер для синхронизации заметок в Joplin по [этому](https://docs.vultr.com/how-to-host-a-joplin-server-with-docker-on-ubuntu) гайду. Сервер джоплина не может подключиться к postgresql. В логах постгреса

```
2024-02-29 14:40:36.386 UTC [460] FATAL: password authentication failed for user "joplin-user"
2024-02-29 14:40:36.386 UTC [460] Detail: Role "joplin-user" does not exist.
```

joplin-docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
    db:
        image: postgres:13
        volumes:
            - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
            - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
            - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DATABASE}
    app:
        image: joplin/server:latest
        depends_on:
            - db
        ports:
            - "127.0.0.1:80:80"
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            - APP_PORT=80
            - APP_BASE_URL=${APP_BASE_URL}
            - DB_CLIENT=pg
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
            - POSTGRES_DATABASE=${POSTGRES_DATABASE}
            - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
            - POSTGRES_PORT=${POSTGRES_PORT}
            - POSTGRES_HOST=db
```

Пытался подключиться через докер, получал такую же ошибку, что пользователь не существует.

Answer (score -1):

Оказалось, я поменял пароль в .env. Удалил папку "Data", запустил контейнер заново и все починилось.